# Intellij - How do I treat warnings as errors that will prevent compilation?

Tags: intellij-idea

How do I treat warnings as errors that will prevent compilation in Intellij?  I figured out how to change the inspection severity to error, and that will underline the problem in red, but compilation still succeeds.  And also it doesn't show any red underlines in the project view like a normal error does.

Answer (score 5):

There is a request for such a feature: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-78625
Please vote for it.

Comment: I created a JetBrains account just to vote for this.

Answer (score 4):

IntelliJ can't change the rules that govern the compiler; the red-yellow-green is intended to influence *your* behavior.

Only proceed if IntelliJ shows green; ask your teammates to do so as well.

Comment: Is there any way that I could get the inspection error to show up on the project window or someplace else? As it is now, it seems that I would actually have to open the file with the problem to see the problem.

Comment: You can also run the Inspector and see all the issues at once.

Comment: Is there a way to indicate warnings in the project structure like red errors?

Comment: Yellow, of course.  All configurable in the Inspections section.